# UIApplication SendEvent crash

Tags: ios, uikit, uiapplication

I am developing sample application where i am subclassing `UIApplication` and overriding `sendEvent` function.Everything works good but however sometime i am getting exception in the function, is their any possibility that `[UIApplication SendEvent]` may through exception??..following is my code..

```
 (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [super sendEvent:event]; 


//Some other things just checking for type of event..etc...

}
```

I get crash SIGSEGV just after calling  `[super sendEvent:event];` .

Comment: Also seeing the same but it is rare.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move `[super sendEvent:event]` at the end of your routine.

If you are intercepting, you should call the super class method last and not first. If you call the super method first, it will pass the event to all responders that may eventually eat it.